# RallyRestApi Cannot parse object reference from hierarchicalrequirement

Tags: .net, rest, task, rally

I'm using the `Rally.RestApi.dll` to create a set of task against a user story (US).  The US already exists within rally so I want to create a set of template tasks against this.

Using the following code I get an error message "`Cannot parse object reference from /hierarchicalrequirement/[Parent ID]`"

```
RallyRestApi rallyRestApi = new RallyRestApi("<username>", "<password>", "https://rally1.rallydev.com", "1.39");
DynamicJsonObject jsonObject = new DynamicJsonObject();
jsonObject["Name"] = "Dev Task";
jsonObject["WorkProduct"] = "/hierarchicalrequirement/US1234";
jsonObject["Estimate"] = 10;
jsonObject["ToDo"] = 10;
jsonObject["TaskType"] = "Dev";
jsonObject["Team"] = "QA";
CreateResult createResult = rallyRestApi.Create("task", jsonObject);
```

So the question is, how do you create a child item (task) in rally and associate it with a parent (US)?

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.  You just need to use the story's ObjectID rather than its FormattedID:

```
jsonObject["WorkProduct"] = "/hierarchicalrequirement/1412304834"; //object id
```